# Which language should i go for when developing mobile device apps

Tags: java, windows-mobile, java-me, mobile, symbian

I see quite some variety of languages/technologies available to develop for the mobile devices/ palms, PDAs, etc such as JavaME, Windows Mobile etc. And now we see Android emerging up.

Question:

Which language/technology would you suggest for development for these devices, something that should could be emerging and future compatible.

Also which language targets the more devices or in other words which is more profitable?

Where does symbian technology stand here.

Am I right if i go for JavaME?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are considering only the programming language itself Java is available on almost all mobile devices.  Even iPhone support is available through http://www.flexycore.com/.

However, the language itself doesn't matter much.  Because the device specific APIs are very very different.  Even among Java ME you'd have to use proprietary APIs if you want to utilize all the features of the device in which your application would run.

So the best way to choose a platform would depend on which device's market you're targeting and see as most profitable.

Comment: @Chandru: That is great explanation and you have pointed out things that i did not know about. Thanks +1

But there are some other points in my question i will be looking for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is for common developing

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677133.aspx

This is java based

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)

this is for windows based

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677133.aspx

read this you will clear idea about that.

Comment: @ratty: that is wealth of info thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

It has more to do with your target platform(s) and the connectivity of those platforms.  If you are targeting feature phones, android devices, or the iPhone .NET is already out.  If all your target devices have web connectivity I would recommend going with web development targeting mobile screen resolutions.  If your looking to target mobile development a year or two out I would look at Flash(Flex) and Silverlight.

Comment: You *can* do .NET development on iPhone with MonoTouch, and I've seen a port of Mono to Droid as well (though currently experimental).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the app you want to make. Is it a game? If it is, then Java ME is good. There are plenty of games created with it already, and it is supported on a large number of phones, though its implementation is not the same across all vendors.

However, since you do seem to be leaning towards something that is coming up, Java ME might not be such a good idea. The platform is a bit old and a bit stale, honestly. Android is better in this regard, and I believe its API allows you more freedom than what Java ME affords. I can't speak for Windows Mobile as I've never touched it.

If you are interested in developing for Symbian, I'd suggest looking at the [Forum Nokia website](http://www.forum.nokia.com/).

Comment: @colig: Thanks for your advice, got to think about it again.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this Infographics](http://www.brilsystems.com/mobile-app-programming-languages/). Really wonderful visualization of the answer.